# PHP PDO, need to ensure i understand what i coded?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

Can someone tell me when you `prepare()` a statement (in my case an update statement) and then `execute()` it, I then check using `rowCount()` after the update query (see code below) if `rowCount() > 0` if it is then a match was found and update took place, but I then got an else statement.

To make sure I am not confusing myself with syntax errors and conditions in statements, I want to ask in my code below (have commented specific area in detail) does the else statement basically mean **cannot update because a match was not found** and/or a possible syntax error or some other error? I think it means what I put in bold just want to ensure I am not confusing myself.

Please ignore the SQL UPDATE syntax itself in the prepare statement as it's wrong and will deal with later. I think the code explains better along with a detailed comment in area I am talking about.

```
// check if key is set and alphanumeric and equals 40 chars long
// we use sha1 so it will always be 40 chars long.
if(isset($_GET['key']) && ctype_alnum($_GET['key']) && strlen($_GET['key']) == 40){
$key = trim($_GET['key']);
}

// if key isset and valid
if(isset($key)){


try {
    // connect to database
    $dbh = sql_con();

    // checke if activation key matches and user_uid matches
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
            SELECT
              users_status.user_uid,
              users_status.user_activation_key
            FROM
              users_status
            JOIN
              users
            ON
              users_status.user_activation_key = ?
            AND
              users_status.user_uid = users.user_uid LIMIT 1");

    // execute query
    $stmt->execute(array($key));

    // if row count greater than 0 then match found
    if ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {

        // user verified; we now must update users status in users table to active = 1
        // and set the user_activation_key in the users_status to NULL
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
            UPDATE
              users.user_status,
              users_status.user_activation_key
            SET
              user_status = ".USER_STATUS_ACTIVE.",
              user_activation_key = NULL
            JOIN
              users
            ON
              users_status.user_activation_key = ?
            AND
              users_status.user_uid = users.user_uid LIMIT 1");

        // execute query
        $stmt->execute(array($key));

        if ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {

            echo 'account now activated';
            exit;

        } else {
            // update not sucessful
            // THIS IS THE BIT IM CONFUSED WITH;
            // IF RETURNED RESULT IS 0 (WHICH IT WILL BE IF I GET HERE WHEN RUNNING SCRIPT)
            // THEN I GUESS THAT MEANS THERE WAS NOT AN ERROR IN SQL SYNTAX BUT
            // CONDITION IN SQL STATEMENT COULD NOT BE MATCHED ? IS THAT CORRECT WHAT I AM THINKING ?
            // IF I AM CORRECT THEN OBVIOUSLY I WILL DISPLAY A MESSAGE TO USER AND EXIT HERE;
            // AS IF I AM THINKING RITE ANY SYNTAX ERROR WOULD BE CAUGHT BY CATCH BLOCK AND THIS ELSE STATEMENT
            // MEANS COULD NOT UPDATE BECAUSE NO MATCH IN UPDATE QUERY COULD BE FOUND ?
        }


    } // else no match found
    else {

        // no match found invalid key
        echo '<h1>Invalid Activation Link</h1>';

        $SiteErrorMessages =
        "Oops! Your account could not be activated. Please recheck the link in your email.
        The activation link could not be found or the account has already been activated.";

        SiteErrorMessages();

        include($footer_inc);
        exit;

    }

    // close database connection
    $dbh = null;

} // if any errors found log them and display friendly message
catch (PDOException $e) {
    ExceptionErrorHandler($e);
    require_once($footer_inc);
    exit;
}

} else {

// else key not valid or set
echo '<h1>Invalid Activation Link</h1>';

$SiteErrorMessages =
"Oops! Your account could not be activated. Please recheck the link in your email.
The activation link appears to be invalid.<br /><br />
If the problem persists please request a new one <a href='/member/resend-activation-email'>here</a>.";

SiteErrorMessages();

include($footer_inc);
exit;

}
```

Comment: If you're asking for feedback on improving working code then you're better off asking on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No i'm not i am asking if my thinking logic is correct.

Comment: What does `msqls()` do? If it's any kind of escaping, get rid of it. By using PDO prepared statements you do not have to escape; actually, escaping would add additional backslashes or quotes which you usually do not want in your database.

Comment: Yes it was from old code and was an escape function, i meant to have removed it, will edit now to stop any confusion. Thanks phplover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right:

```
if $stmt->rowCount() == 0
```

Then it means no rows has been updated.

If you heve sql errors or errors while executing query you receive a FALSE return value or also a PDO EXCEPTION when you execute

```
  execute(array($key));
```

Comment: Ok thank you, i understand the `$stmt->rowCount() == 0` now, but the execute part which you have highlighted, should i also be putting those in if statements ? as i thought using a try and catch block any errors like syntax errors will be caught in the catch block and if the `execute(array($key));` failed for whatever reason it would be caught in the catch block ? thanks phplover

Comment: putting the execute in an if-else statement is a good idea: if(execute == true) ... else "Query failed" this way any possible query failueres that don't generate PDO exceptions are managed

Comment: Ok thanks, i thought a catch block would catch execute() if it failed, i must be confusing myself with the catch part or something. thanks phplover

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing more than one update, you should really make use of transactions.

Note though, transactions are not supported in the default MyISAM engine, so you'd need to `ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENGINE=InnoDB` if you want this to work:

```
$success = false;
$dbh->beginTransaction();
# perform your first query
if ($query->rowCount() == 1) {
   # something was updated/inserted/deleted
   # perform second query
   if ($query->rowCount() == 1) {
       $success = true;
   }
}

if ($success) $dbh->commit();
else $dbh->rollBack();
```

As for your question, you probably need to surround your ? with single-quotes so change your statement to this:

```
users_status.user_activation_key = '?';
```

Another reason why you might not be getting a result, is if your $key is an integer and you use the `PreparedStatement::execute($array)` method to bind your parameters, you need to ensure you cast the values to the proper types for it to work, example:

```
$query->execute(array((int)$key));
```

Otherwise just use `$query->bindParam($key)`

Comment: Hi, using transactions in this code is not what i want, i first need to ensure the activation key in the `$_GET['key']` matches in the **users_status** table and the user_uid in the user_status table also matches the one in the **users** table. if a match is found i then do an update query but if no match found then obviously the activation link is invalid. Also i am sure that you are not to place **?** in single/double quotes as it's not needed, i maybe wrong but thought you don't place them in quotes, also it's not that i am getting a result, i just want to make sure i am thinking correctly

Comment: @PHPLOVER I'm not actually sure about the single-quote, but i've heard people complaining about it in comments on some tutorial about PHPs PDO. Just have a look at the table in phpMyAdmin and see if your SQL statement should actually be finding a value or not. And oh, you are doing things correctly as far as I can see. The problem is that the PDO object makes queries so much easier to read/follow than the old my_sql_rubbish so it may confuse you.

Comment: yeah i think i'm confusing myself when it comes to try and catch blocks (ie, when i should use them) confusing myself with exceptions etc.